# Dynamic select menu not working after change event

Tags: javascript, meteor

Im trying to make a dynamic select menu where you select a customer and then filter the contacts for that customer.

when i select a customer it properly filters the contacts but the customer select menu does not show that anything is selected.

```
<template name="newLeadForm">

<form id="lead">
    <fieldset>
        <legend>New Lead</legend>
        <br/>
        <select id="customer_id" class="span12">
            <option id="null" value="null">Select One</option>
            {{#each customers}}<option id="{{id}}" value="{{_id}}">{{name}} - {{city}}, {{state}} {{zip}}</option>{{/each}}
        </select>
        <select id="contact_id" class="span12">
            <option id="null" value="null">Select One</option>
            {{#each contacts}}<option id="{{id}}" value="{{_id}}">{{first_name}} {{last_name}}</option>{{/each}}
        </select>

        <input id="submit" type="submit" class="btn">
    </fieldset>
</form>

</template>
```

Here is the data being supplied to the template

```
Template.newLeadForm.customers = function () {
return Customers.find();
};

Template.newLeadForm.contacts = function () {
console.log(Session.get("_customer_id"));
return Contacts.find({customer_id: Session.get("_customer_id")});
};
```

and the event handlers

```
Template.insert.events({
'change form#lead #customer_id' : function (event) {
    customer = $("form#lead #customer_id").val();
    Session.set("_customer_id", $("form#lead #customer_id").val());

},

'submit form#lead' : function (event) {

    if (event.type === 'click' || event.type === 'submit') {

        event.preventDefault();

        var customer_id = $("#customer_id").val();
        var contact_id = $("#contact_id").val();
        var lead_source_id = $("#lead_source_id").val();
        var lead_number = $("#lead_number").val();

        if(Leads.insert({id: Leads.find().count() + 1, customer_id: customer_id, contact_id: contact_id})) {
            $("#customer_id").val(null);
            $("#contact_id").val(null);
            Session.set("_customer_id", null);
        }   
    }
}   
});
```

Comment: You could also put your contacts in another template using `{{>template}}` and change that one instead, so the `newLeadForm` isn't re-rendered

Comment: @Akshat your answer is what worked if you post it as an answer I will accept is the answer.

Answer (score 2):

After Meteor re-renders the option elements in your select element, you should tell it to set the `selectedIndex` property on the select element so that it updates. You can do this with the `rendered` event:

```
Template.newLeadForm.rendered = function() {
  $("#customer_id")[0].selectedIndex = 5; // possibly track the index so you know what to set it to
}
```

Comment: I added this function the insert event but it does not seem to be doing the trick.

Comment: I'm not sure I explained the problem so well. Pretty much after you have made your selection in the first drop down it filters he results as expected but say if you change your selection on the first drop down it will update the results for the second drop down but the first drop down will go back the default of showing nothing selected "select one". Thanks for your answer anyway ill try and do more research on the rendering

Answer (score 0):

Simple workaround:

```
Template.newLeadForm.rendered = function(){
  $('#customer_id').val(Session.get("_customer_id"))
}
```

Since `newLeadForm` depends on Session["_customer_id"], it will be re-rendered whenever Session["syntax"] changes, and thus `template.hello.rendered` will be called every time Session["syntax"] changes.

---

Another option, you can add an autorun for each select you want to keep updated:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  Meteor.startup(function() {
    Deps.autorun(keep_cust_select_updated)
  })

  function keep_cust_select_updated(){
    $('#customer_id').val(Session.get("_customer_id"))
  }
}
```

Whenever the `Session.set("_customer_id", xxxx)` is called, keep_select_updated will be rerun (as it is dependent on `Session.get("_customer_id")`) and the correct value will be selected (by the jQuery `$('#customer_id').val(...)` call).

The advantage of the latter method is you don't need to bother adding `"selected"` correctly into the html for each `<option>`